# Representing a 5-cycle as a product of transpositions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Dr. Pinter's "A Book of Abstract Algebra" shows that:

$$(12345)$$

can be written as the following product of transpositions:

$$(54)(53)(52)(51)$$

How can the first representation, $(12345)$, be represented as $(54)(53)(52)(51)$?

Comment: Do you understand what the $(12345)$ and $(53)$ notations mean?

Comment: I *think* that $(12345)$ means: $f(1)=2$, $f(2)=3$, etc.

Comment: @KevinMeredith You are missing a $5 \mapsto 1$. Also, do you understand what the notation $(54)(53)$ means?

Comment: The composition is taken from right to left.

Comment: @A.P., I believe that they're composed. Example: $f = (54)(53)$, so $f(3)$  equals $4$, since 3 -> 5, and then 4 -> 5.

Comment: Indeed, it is a shorthand for composition, with the caveat that you can only read it from right to left: you have $3 \mapsto 5 \mapsto 4$, $(4 \mapsto ) 4 \mapsto 5$, $5 \mapsto 3 (\mapsto 3)$, so the final result is $(54)(53) = (345)$. I followed what seems to be the convention of your book, but note that many authors read the composition from left to right, instead.

Comment: @KevinMeredith Don't you mean "product of transpositions" not compositions?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to see what's going on:

$$\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \end{matrix} 
\quad \xrightarrow{(51)} \quad 
\begin{matrix} 5 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ 1 \end{matrix} 
\quad \xrightarrow{(52)} \quad 
\begin{matrix} 5 \\ 1 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ 2\end{matrix} 
\quad \xrightarrow{(53)} \quad 
\begin{matrix} 5 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 4 \\ 3 \end{matrix} 
\quad \xrightarrow{(54)} \quad
\begin{matrix} 5 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \end{matrix}
 $$

and
$$\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \end{matrix} 
\quad \xrightarrow{(12345)} \quad 
\begin{matrix} 5 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \end{matrix}$$

Comment: Nice visual! (3 more characters needed...)

Answer (score 0):

In general, this is just an observation that any cycle can be decomposed into transpositions via the above method. Direct computation shows that they are the same permutation, and if we write

$(r_1r_2\cdots r_n)= (r_nr_{n-1})(r_nr_{n-2})\cdots (r_n)(r_1)$

we can show the equality holds by the same method.

For instance, choose $r_k$ with $k\neq n$. The first spot it appears (starting from the right) will be in the $k$th spot. It is in the transposition $(r_nr_k)$ so $r_k\mapsto r_n$. Then, $r_n$ will appear in the very next transposition so $r_n\mapsto r_{k+1}$ and $r_{k+1}$ is fixed. For $k=n$ we have that $r_n$ appears in the first transposition so $r_n\mapsto r_1$ and $r_1$ is fixed. But this is by definition the $n$-cycle we started with (i.e. $r_1\mapsto r_2 \mapsto \cdots \mapsto r_n \mapsto r_{1}$).